# DX10223: Lifetime validation failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I have working prototype Visual Studio Solution using IdentityServer4 netstandard2.0 which has:

- IdentityServer (asp.net core mvc)

  - AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials
  - RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse
  - RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding
- Web project (asp.net core mvc)
- API project (asp.net core mvc)

Sometimes, when acceding to API project, I've got the following error :

> DX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired.

How and where can I refresh token ?

Is it possible to refresh token on API project ?

Comment: Try checking server timezone & current time setting. The token available for 1 hour, using wrong time settings may expire the token faster than expected.

Comment: And if I would like to not have expiration until user disconnection ?

Comment: You can consider using `AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server` instead of `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect`. This problem is related to OAuth token validity, check if the token has proper expiration time (I don't know so much how OAuth token expiration works).

Answer (score 2):

Tokens have finite lifetimes. They will expire at some point.

Refresh tokens are a mechanism for certain application types to request new access tokens without direct user interaction.

The refresh token related settings are described here:
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/refresh_tokens.html

You refresh a token by sending the refresh token to the token endpoint. This will return a new access token.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6

The IdentityModel library has a `TokenClient` class which wraps the token endpoint interactions in C#

https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2

Comment: Thanks a lot.
But have you got a sample which updates claims on my Web project and my API project too ?

Comment: This sentence does not make sense.

Comment: Yes, sorry I was lost. 

I found solution by adding hidden iframe which call a refresh by interval in my Web project. So the token is renewed before expiration. Now my web user can stay on same page few days with the autorization to call ajax Api project.

Thanks for your help and long life to security !

Answer (score 0):

As @Tetsuya Yamamoto said - first check timezone and time setting. Anyway you set lifetime of identity servers clients tokens for example in config like: "AccessTokenLifetime": 86400